# Series including binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$\Sigma_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n} e^{cn( x + y)}$

I know that you can write $\Sigma_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}=2^n$ but I cannot do this right now because I have the exponential factor.

Then I though of expressing $ e^{cn( x + y)}= \Sigma_{n=0}^N \frac{[cn(x + y)]^n}{n!} $

But this only complicates things further.

Any tips on how I should proceed ?

Edit: c,y,x are constants

Comment: Side note: Use `\sum` for the sum sign, not `\Sigma`

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ the variables of the function and $c$ a constant?

Comment: all 3 constants

Comment: Oh ,cool, then my answer should be right :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $z=e^{c(x+y)}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k}e^{ck(x+y)}=\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k}z^k={(1+z)}^N={(1+e^{c(x+y)})}^N$

$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k}z^k={(1+z)}^N$

The above statement is just from Newton's binomial theorem if we plug $x=1$ and $y=z$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

I would say that this is a pretty nice form

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but is the 3rd step a formula?

Comment: I will search for some info or if I can't find any, I will prove it to you

Comment: I hope that now, everything is clear